# Wait for previous function to complete

Tags: c#

I'm working on a web installer and one of the things I have currently is

```
    void MoveFiles()
    {
        lbldlstatus.Text = "Moving Files";
        string InstallDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/DoxramosRepack-master";
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(InstallDirectory);
        foreach(var file in d.GetFiles("*"))
        {
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(file.Name)) {
                File.Delete(file.Name);
            }

                Directory.Move(file.FullName, file.Name);
                Cleanup();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                lbldlstatus.Text = "Repack Installation Failed";
            }
        }            
    }
    void Cleanup()
    {
        lbldlstatus.Text = "Cleaning Up Files";
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists("Repack.zip"))
            {
                File.Delete("Repack.zip");
            }
            if(Directory.Exists("DoxramosRepack-master"))
            {
                Directory.Delete("DoxramosRepack-master");
            }
            lbldlstatus.Text = "Repack Installed Successfully";
        }
```

When I get to `Cleanup()` I have a `System.IO.IOException`.

> Process cannot access the file Repack.zip because it being used by
>   another process.

The full code runs

Download->Extract->Move->Cleanup.

I'm not sure what process is being used, but I'm looking to find a way for each process to wait for the previous to finish before starting.

Comment: I don't think you are using async methods anywhere so probably you don't close a file correctly..

Comment: The code to extract is probably not being closed or disposed of properly thus when you try to delete the zip file it is still in use. Given that the extract code is not shown it cannot be confirmed if that is the case.

Comment: When I get back to my PC I'll throw my download, extract and move on paste bin after I read into dispose if that's not the problem.  Thanks guys

Comment: http://pastebin.com/miswqwA3 is the code itself for everything. I was first trying to figure out how I would use client.Dispose() inside of the download complete helper, realized I can't just dispose of it during the main function and I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to extract code below

```
void Extract()
{
    string zipPath = @"Repack.zip";
    string extractPath = @".";
    try
    {
        using (ZipFile unzip = ZipFile.Read(zipPath))
        {
            unzip.ExtractAll(extractPath);
            lbldlstatus.Text = "Extracting Files";
            MoveFiles();               
        }
    }
    catch (ZipException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        lbldlstatus.Text = "Repack Installation Failed";
    }
}
```

You are calling the move files before you are finish with the zip file. Seeing as the move file method is responsible for calling the clean up function then you should make sure that the zip file is already disposed of before trying to delete it.

```
void Extract()
{
    string zipPath = @"Repack.zip";
    string extractPath = @".";
    try
    {
        using (ZipFile unzip = ZipFile.Read(zipPath))
        {
            unzip.ExtractAll(extractPath);
            lbldlstatus.Text = "Extracting Files";
        }
        MoveFiles();
    }
    catch (ZipException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        lbldlstatus.Text = "Repack Installation Failed";
    }
}
```

Clean up should also be called after everything has been moved. Currently the example code is calling it repeatedly in the for loop.

Comment: Thanks, didn't even notice I had it in the using block. (I noticed the foreach earlier and had fixed it, but thank you for pointing it out as well)

Answer (score 1):

The code which you pasted on pastebin is different from what you have posted here. The code in pastebin never calls cleanup.

Anyways the problem is because you are calling `MoveFiles()` from within the `using` block here:

```
using (ZipFile unzip = ZipFile.Read(zipPath))
{
    unzip.ExtractAll(extractPath);
    lbldlstatus.Text = "Extracting Files";
    MoveFiles();       
}
```

Move it outside the using block.